# replace and add multiple lines using findall

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7, findall

I am trying to add multiple lines to a file (input.txt) and replace multiple lines in the same file (input.txt) but my code only inserts the lines at end of file. Do you know that how I can fix the code to get the expected output file I want?

**My code:**

```
import re

searchtext1 = """
AB     3.483e-01   2.52e-02 ; 3.46 0.0123
"""
# add these lines after searchtext1
addtext1 = """
CD     2.123e-01   1.31e-02 ; 7.25 0.0145
DE     4.896e-01   7.25e-02 ; 8.25 0.0185
"""
searchtext2 = """
; atom
#atomnumber

#molecule
[weight]
"""
# replace these lines to searchtext2
changetext2 = """
; iron
#48kcal
35 mol
#12 g
"""

with open('input.txt', 'ab+') as infile:
    matches1 = re.findall(r'^(\d+)\.(.*)$', searchtext1, re.MULTILINE)
    infile.write(addtext1)

    matches2 = re.findall(r'^(\d+)\.(.*)$', searchtext2, re.MULTILINE)
    infile.write(changetext2)
```

**input.txt:**

```
[atom]
123
[bonds]
XY     4.212e-01   4.18e-02 ; 8.01 0.0487
AB     3.483e-01   2.52e-02 ; 3.46 0.0123

[molecule]
1 2
3 4
TY     0.412e-01   1.72e-02 ; 0.32 0.0455

; atom
#atomnumber

#molecule
[weight]
calculated value is 5 kcal/mol
end file
```

**expected output file:**

```
[atom]
123
[bonds]
XY     4.212e-01   4.18e-02 ; 8.01 0.0487
AB     3.483e-01   2.52e-02 ; 3.46 0.0123
CD     2.123e-01   1.31e-02 ; 7.25 0.0145
DE     4.896e-01   7.25e-02 ; 8.25 0.0185

[molecule]
1 2
3 4
TY     0.412e-01   1.72e-02 ; 0.32 0.0455

; iron
#48kcal
35 mol
#12 g
calculated value is 5 kcal/mol
end file
```

Comment: What language is that, in your input.txt? I would check if there's a python library that can parse it, then you can interact with it conceptually, instead of hacking the syntax with direct reads and writes.

Comment: It is a normal text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris mentioned in the comments, I'd suggest trying to use a library that can already interact with the format - `configparser` seems like the obvious choice to me, but there could be reasons to not if the format can vary from what is in your question.

That aside, if you want to use `re`, I've updated your code a little. Here's the tweaks I made:

- Removed newlines from the start and end of your triple-quoted strings, as they will become a part of the match, which may or may not be what you want. My personal preference is to be explicit about newlines in the actual replacement.
- Escaped `[` and `]` in your search text, as these are special characters in `re` and will confuse it (they specify a character class).
- Used `with` to open separate input and output files. These are cleaned up when you exit the `with` block. If you really want to replace input.txt, I guess you could just move output.txt over the top afterwards.
- You can use `re.sub` to replace the occurrences directly, rather than searching for them, finding the index in the text and then replacing/appending. In the case of adding text, I've just made the replace out of both `searchtext1` and `addtext1`. (I used an f-string, but you could also do `"{search}\n{add}".format(search=searchtext, add=addtext1)` if you prefer.
- Finally we write the updated text back to disc.

Hope that helps!

```
import re

searchtext1 = """AB     3.483e-01   2.52e-02 ; 3.46 0.0123"""
# add these lines after searchtext1
addtext1 = """CD     2.123e-01   1.31e-02 ; 7.25 0.0145
DE     4.896e-01   7.25e-02 ; 8.25 0.0185"""

searchtext2 = """; atom
#atomnumber

#molecule
\[weight\]"""
# replace these lines to searchtext2
changetext2 = """; iron
#48kcal
35 mol
#12 g"""

with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    intext = infile.read()

    intext = re.sub(searchtext1, f"{searchtext1}\n{addtext1}", intext)
    intext = re.sub(searchtext2, changetext2, intext)

    outfile.write(intext)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have opened your file in append mode “ab+” which specifies that all writes will go to the end of the file. To change parts of a file in the way you are wanting, you must rewrite the entire file.

A common pattern is to create a new tempfile, write your new data, then move the new file over your old one. This way the overwrite is atomic and you stand less chance of losing data if your program crashes.

Comment: How can I do that?